# How to create a new shape when variable equals new month

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a loop that checks if cells in a range fall between two dates. My loop currently creates a new shape for every cell that is between the given date ranges.

I want my loop to take the first given date range and output the sum of all cells within the my range that fall between the date range. I also want the loop to title the cell above the shape with the month it searched.
My date ranges are `startDate` and `endDate`
**Code**

```
Sub foo()
Dim oval As Shape
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim h As Integer
Dim w As Integer
Dim x As Long
Dim shp As Object
Dim counter As Long
Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:B6")


h = 495
startDate = "01/01/2019"
endDate = "03/10/2019"

For Each rCell In rng
    If IsDate(rCell.Value) Then
        If rCell.Value >= startDate And rCell.Value <= endDate Then

            counter = counter + 1

            Set oval = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, h + 70 * (counter - 1), w + 125, 60, 65)

            With oval
                .Line.Visible = True
                .Line.Weight = 2
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                .TextFrame.Characters.Caption = rCell.Value
                .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
                .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 12
                .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
                .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next rCell

End Sub
```

**Desired Output**
[image]

**Current Output**
[image]

Comment: I'm confused `output the sum of all cells within the given range that fall in the date range` ? Your given range is A1 to A7. Are you trying to compare both and b?

Comment: @pgSystemTester yes, I am trying to compare my date range the `A1:A7`

Comment: why is March in your desired output? I see the 6 cells in column B, but you aren't compareing to it? BTW did you based this off of my code... this looks like my writing.... 

Comment: @pgSystemTester apologies on the typo. Edited my post. My range is `A1:B6` I did not base it off your code. I got the answer from someone else on here

Comment: @pgSystemTester my second loop request is a bit confusing which is why I posted a picture of what I want the loops to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to basically sum by a month, and to do that an array is probably the easiest thing to do. I'll assume it's only one year at time, but you could lookup Redim Preserver to make that change.

This is incrementing every value in the set range and adding it to the array corresponging to the month number.

```
 Sub BoOm()
Dim YourSTuff(1 To 12, 0 To 0) As Long, aCell As Range, YourRNG As Range, startDate As Date, endDate As Date

Set YourRNG = Range("A1:B99")

startDate = "01/01/2019"
endDate = "03/10/2019"


For Each aCell In YourRNG.Cells
    If IsDate(aCell.Value) Then
        If aCell.Value >= startDate And aCell.Value <= endDate Then
            YourSTuff(Month(aCell), 0) = YourSTuff(Month(aCell), 0) + 1
        End If
    End If
Next aCell


'when you're done.
Dim i As Long, c As Long
c = 1
    For i = LBound(YourSTuff) To UBound(YourSTuff)
        If YourSTuff(i, 0) > 0 Then


                Set Oval = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, h + 70 * (c), w + 125, 60, 65)
                c = c + 1

                With Oval
                    'not sure how to format as you want
                    .Line.Visible = True
                    .Line.Weight = 2
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Caption = Choose(i, "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "" & _
                     "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December") & Chr(10) & YourSTuff(i, 0)
                    .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
                    .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 12
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
        End If


    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: your code almost does what I want, I just have to figure out how to evenly distribute the shapes. My original code distributes them as shown in my picture

Comment: and i just figured it out LOL. Thanks for your help. Now the edited code is yours ;)

Comment: is there any way for your solution to display the circles with the days out of the week for one week worth of dates, say "3/3/2019 - 3/9/2019"

Comment: @jose You would modify your caption text depending on what date you want. Here's an example code of displaying the date you described: https://pastebin.com/VD3hBZyG